# C#: Dynamicly Add Items to Scrollview Control in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, list, class

Currently I am trying to code a WPF application that will store books and users for an imaginary library(I need to prove someone wrong). In my code, I have a class for Books and one for users. Inside of each will be a static list that keeps track of them all. What I would like to do is list out all the books and users so the viewer can see them. I thought I could do this with a scrollview and add labels to it that store the information(This would be in a separate window than the main screen, you would get there by pressing a button). However, I have been having some trouble with this.

LibraryCore:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LibraryCore
{
class User
{

}
class Books
{
    public static List<Books> bookslist = new List<Books>();

    public static void NewBook(string _title, string _author, string _publisher, int _isbn, int _count = 1)
    {
        bookslist.Add(new Books(_title, _author, _publisher, _isbn, _count));
    }

    public static void AddBook(string _title, int _amount)
    {
        bookslist[bookslist.FindIndex(b => b.Title.ToUpper() == _title.ToUpper())].Count += _amount;
    }
    public List<Books> currentLoans = new List<Books>();

    public string Publisher { get; private set; }
    public string Author { get; private set; }
    public string Title { get; private set; }

    public int ISBN { get; private set; }
    public int Count { get; private set; }

    Books(string _title, string _author, string _publisher, int _isbn, int _count = 1)
    {
        Title = _title;
        Author = _author;
        Publisher = _publisher;
        ISBN = _isbn;
        Count = _count;
    }
}
}
```

MainWindow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using LibraryCore;

namespace LibraryLikeWpf
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnNewBook_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Books.NewBook("Odessy", "SOME OLD GUY", "Athens Inc.", 0);
        //Books.NewBook("OLD YELLER", "SOME OLD GUY", "Athens Inc.", 2);
        //Books.NewBook("This old man", "SOME OLD GUY", "Athens Inc.", 1);
    }

    private void btnInfo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BookList bookList = new BookList();
        bookList.Show();
    }
}
}
```

BookListWindow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using LibraryCore;

namespace LibraryLikeWpf
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for BookList.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class BookList : Window
{
    public BookList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for(int b = 0; b < Books.bookslist.Count; b++)
        {
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            lbl.Content = String.Format("Title: {0} Author: {1} Publisher: {2} ISBN: {3}",Books.bookslist[b].Title,Books.bookslist[b].Author, Books.bookslist[b].Publisher, Books.bookslist[b].ISBN);
            lbl.Width = 100000;
            scrollGrid.Children.Add(lbl);
        }
    }
}
}
```

This code works, but if I add several Books, the BookListWindow will just overlap the labels and I would like to know how to change their position when they are instantiated. Also, the labels get cut off even though their width shouldn't inhibit that. Why does that happen and how can I fix it? Also, is there a better way to list out ALL of the items in a list in a better looking way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are using XAML, try to use ListView with Binding.

Create a ObservableCollection of Books and bind this to your ListView, this way you can control show your items are shown.